# Disable SSL browsing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I need to disable SSL browsing completely in Chrome.  If not completely, at least disable https://www.facebook.com and force http://www.facebook.com to load, FOR EXAMPLE (FB is just an example - i understand that TODAY it does not permit non-secure browsing).

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, i corrected the question, which isnt about FB, but about browsing in general.  i used FB as an example of a domain by domain approach.

Comment: There is an option in Chrome to disable the various versions of TLS, SSL2, and SS3.  If you do that then Chrome will refuse any SSL connection.  Chrome can be configured to be used in an office setting.

Comment: QUESTION: why did someone downvote this question?  whoever did, please enlighten me.

Comment: I'm curious as to which for which reason you need this?

Comment: @LordT some user scripts under tampermonkey (greasemonkey in firefox) will not work with SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not offer a publicly documented way to disable SSL/TLS.

Neither does Firefox, but it used to contain this capability up to version 3.*.

Comment: tks @daniel.  it is indeed a pity when a browser decides what is best for you and gives you no option.

Comment: It wouldn’t really help anyway. If you don’t want to surf on encrypted pages, you can “enforce” this by yourself, manually. If a website is only offered via HTTPS, there’s really nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because facebook will redirect you to https. And if the browser cannot do https it will just fail to access facebook.

Comment: thanks, i corrected the question, which isnt about FB, but about browsing in general. i used FB as an example of a domain by domain approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the browser to use no ssl at all you can change the proxy settings, so that it does use a non-existing proxy for ssl and no proxy for the rest. If you need this to be done fo specific sites only you maybe can do this with a *.pac file which returns depending on the target a non-existing proxy or 'direct'.

Comment: dont know if i understood your answer.  lemme check it out and i will get back to you, ok?  tks 4 taking the time to help! ;)